# Trying to pass terraform variables through cli

Tags: terraform, environment-variables, cicd, terraform-cli

I'm trying to pass terraform variables through CLI because they are dependent on my github actions workflow. So my main.tf currently looks like this.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "etl_pipeline_test" {
  function_name = var.project_name
  image_uri = "${var.ecr_repo_uri}:${var.image_tag}"
  package_type = "Image"
  role = aws_iam_role.etl_pipeline_test.arn
}
```

It's just a terraform file which creates a lambda function from an ECR docker image.
But I'm not using any variables.tf file so I just want to pass the ecr_repo_uri and image_tag through cli. So currently I'm running this command.
`terraform init && terraform apply -var "ecr_repo_uri=<ecr_repo_uri_var>" -var "image_tag=v0.0"`
To remove any confusion there is a valid ecr_repo_uri. Now I keep getting this error.

```
╷
│ Error: Value for undeclared variable
│
│ A variable named "ecr_repo_uri" was assigned on the command line, but the root module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a "variable"    
│ block to the configuration.
╵
╷
│ Error: Value for undeclared variable
│
│ A variable named "image_tag" was assigned on the command line, but the root module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a "variable" block 
│ to the configuration.
```

I think the problem is in my main.tf, maybe you need to address variables through cli different then with `env.var` like I'm doing right now. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you define the variables accordingly, you cannot arbitrarily use them.

Comment: Yes indeed, I though you only had to do this when you already defined them. Thanks for looking into my problem though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to create a `variable.tf` file where you need to define the variables you are passing through with cli. For other people who might encouter this error, this is my variable.tf file.

```
variable "image_tag" {
  type=string
}
variable "ecr_repo_uri" {
  type=string
}
```

I thought you only had to create a `variable.tf` file when you already defined the variables, but you also have to do this when passing them through cli.